# Laravel - SQL Server connection fail for user "sa"

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel-5

I'm trying to learn more about Laravel framework but get stuck on the database connection issue.

I already double-check the hostname, database name, username and the password and it's all correct. But when i try to do `php artisan migrate` function in my composer, it shows the error like this

`SQLSTATE[28000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'sa'.`

I don't know why is this happened, I try connecting the database using pure PHP syntax too and there's no problem. Could somebody explain ? I appreciates for any kind of information from here. Thanks a lot before..

Here is my `.env` file :

```
DB_CONNECTION=sqlsrv
DB_HOST=NDUT-PC\SQLEXPRESS
DB_DATABASE=SampleDB
DB_USERNAME=sa
DB_PASSWORD=48a365b4ce1e322a55ae9017f3daf0c0
```

And here is my `database.php` file :

```
<?php

return [

    'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'sqlsrv'),

    'connections' => [

        'sqlite' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlite',
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
            'prefix' => '',
        ],

        'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
        ],

        'pgsql' => [
            'driver' => 'pgsql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'schema' => 'public',
            'sslmode' => 'prefer',
        ],

        'sqlsrv' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '1433'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
        ],

    ],

    'migrations' => 'migrations',

    'redis' => [

        'client' => 'predis',

        'default' => [
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
            'database' => 0,
        ],

    ],

];
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: No, I decided to use mysql, until now

Comment: I actually got this to work.  For me, it was related to database permissions... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51529993/unable-to-connect-to-remote-sql-database-from-wamp-server-using-php-7-1 if you're interested.

Comment: thank you, I will try to fix it tonight.

Comment: any solution to problem?

Comment: sadly... not yet.. :(

Comment: Does `NDUT-PC\SQLEXPRESS` run on a different port than the default - i.e. 1433? For example, if it is a secure port then it might be 6433 - if that is the case it would require adding `DB_PORT=6433` to the `.env` file