# Unable to connect to remote SQL database from WAMP Server using PHP 7.1

Tags: php, sql-server, odbc, wamp, php-7.1

I have tried scouring the internet about this, but cannot seem to find a resolution, so I apologise in advance if this is a duplicate as I cannot seem to find anything that helps my situation.

I have setup a new WAMP 3.1.3 Server installation and I'm trying to run a Laravel 5.6 application.  The application connects to a remote MSSQL database on the network and I have this running successfully on my Homestead test environment using the same PHP version (but Ubuntu).

On my WAMP Server (Microsoft Server 2016), I have installed the PHP 7.1 SQL drivers from https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql/releases/tag/v5.3.0. I have edited my `php.ini` files to enable the drivers like so:

```
[PHP_SQLSRV]
extension=php_sqlsrv_71_ts.dll
[PHP_PDO_SQLSRV]
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_71_ts.dll
```

I can visually see in the WAMP tray utility that `php_pdo_sqlsrv_71_ts` and `php_sqlsrv_71_ts` is ticked on and enabled for the PHP extensions.  I have ran `php -m` and can see that the following modules are installed and enabled:

```
...
PDO
pdo_mysql
pdo_sqlite
pdo_sqlsrv
...
```

I have ran phpinfo() and can see that `pdo_sqlsrv` is also installed:
[image]

However, when I attempt a connection to the remote database, I get the following error:
`Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[28000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user ...`

I am using window authentication as the database login, and I have installed SQL Management Studio on my WAMP Server and connected successfully to the database with my windows credentials, so I can verify that it is not a username or password issue.

I can confirm that all details in my `.env` file are correct and are a complete duplicate of my Homestead test environment.

I proceeded to attempt to install the ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server, however, upon installation I get the following error:
`Installation of ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server failed because a higher version already exists on the machine.`

When I check my installed programs it shows that version 11 and 13 are already installed:

[image]

I have also tried enabling the `php_odbc` and `php_pdo_odbc` modules but that didn't make any difference either.

My WAMP setup looks like so:

[image]

I really don't know what else to try. Maybe I have missed something?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it didn't like me trying to access the database via Windows Authentication.  Thanks to this post [Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server : Login failed for user 'sa'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48990621/microsoft-odbc-driver-13-for-sql-server-login-failed-for-user-sa) I was able to determine that SQL was throwing an error about not liking my username/password.

Strangely enough, even though I could access the remote database using my Windows credentials through Management Studio on the same machine, the PHP driver must have been a different story.

I created a new user account against the database and was able to login no problem.